# Serial Port to PHP

Tags: php

I'm new to working with the serial port module to read data from devices and I'm trying to read data from an electronic balance through Nport W2150a device using php with the php_dio module, the code is outputing but the result is printing with unknow charset. What should I do to change that?

Output:

[image: OUTPUT]

Code:

```
<?php

$portName = 'com1:1';
$baudRate = 9600;
$bits = 8;
$spotBit = 1;

header( 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' ); 
?>
<?php
function echoFlush($string)
{
    echo $string . "\n";
    flush();
    ob_flush();
}

if(!extension_loaded('dio'))
{
    echoFlush( "PHP Direct IO does not appear to be installed for more info see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dio.php" );
    exit;
}

try 
{
    $bbSerialPort;
    
    echoFlush(  "Connecting to serial port: {$portName}" );
    
    if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') 
    { 
        $bbSerialPort = dio_open($portName, O_RDWR );
        //we're on windows configure com port from command line
        exec("mode {$portName} baud={$baudRate} data={$bits} stop={$spotBit} parity=n xon=on");
    } 
    else //'nix
    {
        $bbSerialPort = dio_open($portName, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK );
        dio_fcntl($bbSerialPort, F_SETFL, O_SYNC);
        //we're on 'nix configure com from php direct io function
        dio_tcsetattr($bbSerialPort, array(
            'baud' => $baudRate,
            'bits' => $bits,
            'stop'  => $spotBit,
            'parity' => 0
        ));
    }
    
    if(!$bbSerialPort)
    {
        echoFlush( "Could not open Serial port {$portName} ");
        exit;
    }
    
    // send data
    
    $dataToSend = "HELLO WORLD!";
    echoFlush( "Writing to serial port data: \"{$dataToSend}\"" );
    $bytesSent = dio_write($bbSerialPort, $dataToSend );
    echoFlush( "Sent: {$bytesSent} bytes" );
    
    
    $runForSeconds = new DateInterval("PT10S");
    $endTime = (new DateTime())->add($runForSeconds);
    
    echoFlush(  "Waiting for {$runForSeconds->format('%S')} seconds to recieve data on serial port" );
    
    while (new DateTime() < $endTime) {
    
        $data = dio_read($bbSerialPort, 256);
        if ($data) {
            echoFlush(  "Data Recieved: ". $data );
        }
    }
    
    echoFlush(  "Closing Port" );
    
    dio_close($bbSerialPort);

} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    echoFlush(  $e->getMessage() );
    exit(1);
} 

?>
```

Comment: I don't know anything about that specific device, but are you sure that it sends text and not just binary?

Comment: The Nport sends both, but I doubt that the scale sends both. Can't find info about the scane on the internet...

Comment: I tried to read data with RealTerm and It's reading binary

Comment: You can always try and throw [utf8_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php), [utf8_encode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php), [mb_convert_encoding()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) etc. at the wall and see what sticks.